# Unable to load data in QGIS using Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis, pgadmin-4

I created a Postgres database and was able to connect with QGIS desktop but when I import shape files using DB manager the QGIS desktop hangs and data doesn't load.

Comment: How big is your table - QGIS will struggle with millions of records (from my private experience with QGIS). Also why use DBmanager and not import directly from Browser Panel or "Add vector layer"?

Comment: i am just loading a .shp file of 12 MB

Comment: So you import shp from QGIS into postgres DB. Not from DB into QGIS. That is why using DB manager, now understood. Tyr from Processing tools ->Tool Box ->QGIS geoalgorithms -> Database -> Import into PostGis

Comment: Thanks , but how then i load back the data from post gis /postgres into QGIS ?

Comment: I use standard way - by "Browser Panel" configures a connection to Postgres database and load tables directly from it by Browser Panel.
The second way is to add vecor layer by "Add Vecotr Layer" button on left side or from top menu and choose "database". But it is worse and more "ad-hoc"

Comment: I got it, but how about the data i.e the. Shp File that I uploaded from QGIS to Posgres database, how to load that data back in QGIS?

Comment: When you load data from Postgres to Qgis it is a layer. A layer is not equal to Shp. Shp is just one from hundreds of formats for spatial data. Your imported data in Qgis are connected directly to tables in Postgres DB. Every change that you made with them (moving points, adding linestirng, changing attributes) are saving back in DB automatically.
Juz remeber to click "save" (disk icon in qgis) after changes you made on your imported layers